# Problem installing MATLAB R2017a on Ubuntu 17.04 as superuser

Tags: 17.04, matlab

I downloaded the zip file and extracted it, I then went on the terminal and executed

```
sudo ./install
```

and I get all the way through to choosing the installation folder. But I am still getting the error that it failed to create folder even though I'm installing it as a super user. Is there anything I'm supposed to do before installing?

[image: Image of Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I will recommend is to:
create the upper folder in command line:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/MATLAB
```

then run the install program:

```
sudo ./install
```

In case of failure you can try to create the entire path where MatLab will be installed:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a
```